# Syntax error message using the ->with in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone have a look at this, cant figure out why the last line is causing the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $date = $post->created_at;
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'GB');
    $date = $date->formatlocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
    return View::make('posts.show')->('post', $post)with->('date', $date);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Log1c initial answer, you've opened a parenthesis to nothing:

```
return View::make('posts.show')->('post', $post)->with('date', $date);
                             // ^-- HERE, there's no function call
```

Could be you meant to use `with()` there, too?

```
return View::make('posts.show')->with('post', $post)->with('date', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
return View::make('posts.show')->('post', $post)with->('date', $date);
```

it should be:

```
return View::make('posts.show')->with('post', $post)->with('date', $date);
```

change location of `->` as you are calling method `with()`, calling method like `with->()` is invalid syntax and also add one more `with()`.

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried what you suggested but still getting the same error. http://steppic.com/show/5e8e0f33b20aad5957bb86d9e9d08a1f.html

Comment: @runyards, I think now you could at-least voteup. if you found any effort in answer provided